# Exclude single browser from using a CSS class

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'd like to exclude Internet Explorer from using a specific CSS class. 
Is this possible?

Details:

I have a css class that looks like -

```
input[type="radio"]:checked, input[type="radio"]:hover
{
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #90BBD4;
}
```

Since Firefox's latest browser update removed the -moz-box-shadow property and I believe it now uses the default box-shadow instead, ... my Firefox is still working great, but Internet explorer now recognizes it and messes up the look.

How might I go about excluding IE from using this class or work around it somehow?

Comment: Try looking at css3pie to render CSS3 properly in IE: http://css3pie.com/

Comment: 3pie looks like it might do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will set a class of the IE version the client browser is using.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Then using CSS you can target it to a specfic browser by using something like:

```
.ie7 #wrapper
  {
     display:none;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When people feel the need to make their website look different in different browsers (which is the complete opposite of what the Internet should be like...) they use this:

```
<!--[if IE]><html class="ie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>--><html><!--<![endif]-->
```

Then in your CSS you can put `html.ie` to make IE-specific rules.

Comment: I wish it didn't have to be that way, but if IE is going to use those ugly white box radio buttons and checkboxes, something has to be done about them.

Comment: I strongly suggest you [read words of wisdom](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/non-native-ui-sucks.html) and reconsider.

Comment: So your saying leave IE specific faults such as the double margin bug? That doesnt sound very reasonable to me...

Comment: @Sam no, I'm saying don't mess with the default appearance of controls such as checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IE conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) and set css rules in the css you include inside the comment.

For example:

```
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" /><![endif]-->
```

or:

```
<!--[if IE]><style>*ie style rules here*</style><![endif]-->
```