# How to apply a line of css to all browsers but IE?

Tags: css, sass

I don't want to recreate a file just for that specific line of code, I simply want to ignore that css line if I am in Internet Explorer.
I would also like to avoid putting inline css.

> Is it possible?

```
.container {
  height: 100px; // to apply only in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude single browser from using a CSS class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987459/exclude-single-browser-from-using-a-css-class)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a conditional comment.

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
  <style>
    .container {
      height: 100px; /* only in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc */
    }
  </style>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Notice the "not" operator `!` so it will apply to browsers that are not IE. See [this link](https://www.sitepoint.com/internet-explorer-conditional-comments/) for more.

Comment: Sorry if I'm confused, but it seems to me that this condition is written in the html file, since it's enclosing a <style>, which is html markup? My question is about ignoring a css line from within the css file itself, not by ignoring a piece of html that calls some css

Comment: You must remove the style from the css file or at the very least, modify it to check a parent container. I think if you explain the entire problem there might be a better way to solve it. For example, why should IE not set the `height` but Chrome should?